# Recording software for Mac

Tags: osx, audio, music-production

I'm seeking suggestions for recording software runnable on a Mac. Mostly interested in recording guitar, bass, and drums. I don't need anything crazy, but I do need the ability to track time-signature changes mid-song, which last I checked was beyond Garage Band's capabilities.

I bought Logic Express back when I had a ppc Mac. It was decent. I've been out of the game for a few years, so I'm not sure what's the new hotness. Pro Tools costs more than I'm likely to spend, and I'm fairly adept with *nix so I'd consider open-source software even if it takes a bit of setup.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! If you might have a few specific requirements to list up, that might help to "wake up the neighbors" and give you better matching results. No critics, you've listed quite a few already. But mentioning *Pro Tools costs more than I'm likely to spend* e.g. suggests you have a small budget (what's the limit?), for example. Not being my expertise, there might be some features you want and others you rather don't ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have been using [Reaper](http://www.reaper.fm/) for a few years now and I cannot recommend it enough. It might not be as powerful as the industry standard Pro Tools, but for home recording (like what you are asking for) with options for tracking time-signature changes amongst a plethora of other features, I have found it to be the most reasonable DAW that falls somewhere at the end of the middle spectrum of DAW software.